# Split number into an integer and decimal

Tags: java, integer, decimal

Input 23.893 would become INTEGER - 23, DECIMAL - 0.893

Here's the key snippet from my code

```
double realNumber = scan.nextDouble(); \\store the keyboard input in variable realNumber

double integerPart = Math.floor(realNumber); \\round down eg. 23.893 --> 23

double fractionPart = realNumber - integerPart; \\find the remaining decimal
```

When I try this with long numbers the decimal part differs slightly from the actual.

Input - 234.324112341234134 becomes INTEGER - 234.0,

DECIMAL - 0.3241123412341267

Comment: use a regular expression to split it based on the decimal point. You may need to convert to a string to perform substring operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @dasblinkenlight you can use methods from BigDecimal and combine them with a splitter. I wouldn't count the decimal points though, easier to stick with BigDecimal.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String realNumber = "234.324823783782"; 

    String[] mySplit = realNumber.split("\\.");

    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(mySplit[0]);
    BigDecimal real = new BigDecimal(realNumber);
    BigDecimal fraction = real.subtract(decimal);

    System.out.println(String.format("Decimal : %s\nFraction: %s", decimal.toString(),fraction.toString()));

}
```

This outputs the following:
Decimal : 234
Fraction: 0.324823783782

Answer (score 1):

Your program's logic is correct. The problem is the representation that you have selected for your input.

`double` is inherently imprecise, so the lower-order digits are often not represented correctly. To fix this problem, you could use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or even a `String` data type.

If you use `BigDecimal`, simply rewrite your algorithm using the methods of `BigDecimal`. If you use `String`, split user input at the decimal point, and add required zeros and decimal points after the whole part and before the fractional part.